# Laravel using localhost as URL instead of Cloudfront URL defined in filesystem

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-cloudfront

I have a laravel backpack app. My previous colleague was using public_uploads folder to store all images in the server, I was instructed to clean up and put all images on s3.
So lets say for one model called products,
I changed from:

```
    public function setImagesAttribute($value)
    {
        $attribute_name = "images";
        $disk = "public_uploads";
        $destination_path = '/uploads/' . date('Y/m/d');

        $this->uploadMultipleFilesToDisk($value, $attribute_name, $disk, $destination_path);
    }
```

to

```
   public function setImagesAttribute($value)
    {
        $attribute_name = "images";
        $disk = "s3";
        $destination_path = '/uploads/products/' . date('Y/m/d');

        $this->uploadMultipleFilesToDisk($value, $attribute_name, $disk, $destination_path);
    }
```

Accordingly I updated my Filesystem.php folder to include cloudfront url:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'public_uploads' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => public_path(),
        ],

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('CLOUDFRONT_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Symbolic Links
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
    | `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
    | the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
    |
    */

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

];
```

My assets are being rendered like so:

```
                            <div class="category-icon">
                                <img src="{{ asset($product->img) }}" alt="{{ $product->name }}">
                            </div>
```

however when i try to view my updates on localhost the images have the url:
http://localhost:8000/uploads/products/2023/08/17/337c8d8b6c2cf6dae535588772d2551b.png

I have already run php artisan optimize:clear and php artisan optimize.
Why is it appending localhost URL and not cloudfront?

Comment: Can you show the contents of your `.env` for the relevant environment variables?

Comment: So you do not have any variable for `CLOUDFRONT_URL`? Editor you question and add the relevant variables.

Comment: resolved anyways, issue was backpack